# Getting count of a specific value grouped by ID in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I cam trying to get counts of everyone with a 1 in a specific column and tie the sum to a manager.

DF

```
 ID   Full-Time       Manager ID      
 101      0             103 
 102      1             103
 103      1             110
 104      0             107
 105      1             103 
 106      1             107
 107      1             110 
 108      0             107
 109      1             103
 110      1             NaN
```

I just need a count of those with a 1 under `Full-Time` by `Manager ID`

```
 Manager ID    Full-Time count
    103               3
    107               1
    110               2
```

I tried `df[df['Full-Time'].eq(1)].groupby('Manager ID')['Manager ID'].count()`
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your dataframe before group by Manager:

```
>>> (df.loc[df['Full-Time'] == 1]
       .groupby('Manager ID', as_index=False)['Full-Time']
       .count().astype(int))

   Manager ID  Full-Time
0         103          3
1         107          1
2         110          2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.value_counts()`:

```py
x = (
    df[df["Full-Time"].eq(1)]
    .value_counts("Manager ID")
    .reset_index(name="Full-Time count")
    .astype(int)
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   Manager ID  Full-Time count
0         103                3
1         110                2
2         107                1
```

---

Or `pd.crosstab`:

```py
print(pd.crosstab(df['Manager ID'], df['Full-Time'])[1].reset_index().astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

As your flag is a 0/1 your can simply [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby('Manager ID', as_index=False)['Full-Time'].sum()
```

Generic case:

```
df['Full-Time'].eq(1).groupby(df['Manager ID']).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Manager ID  Full-Time
0         103          3
1         107          1
2         110          2
```